Internal energy of a gas and $p$-$V$ curve
The internal energy is said to be same for 2 gases which have undergone 2 different processes.
The same is often explained by a $p$-$V$ curve. If the initial and final final points of 2 different curves are same then the internal energy is same .
My question is - how can we infer that internal energy is same from $p$-$V$ graph.
The internal energy energy depends on temperature ($U=n(f/2)RT $)
U = internal energy of gas molecule
n= no. Of moles
R= Universal gas constant
T= Temperature in kelvin
f=degree of freedom
Is it possible that temp is assumed to be same for both? If yes, then why cant they be different?


If the initial and final final points of 2 different curves are same
then the internal energy is same .

The change in internal energy is the same because the change in internal energy (a property of the gas) does not depend on the path between the initial and final points.  But that doesn't necessarily mean the internal energy is the same.

My question is - how can we infer that internal energy is same from
$p$-$V$ graph.

Based on your subsequent statement: "The internal energy energy depends on temperature" I assume you're referring to an ideal gas.
Take any of one the $pV=$constant curves provided in the answer by Ruffolo. From the ideal gas law, the constant is $nRT$. But as you already know the internal energy is given by $U=n\frac{f}{2}RT$. The value of $f$ depends on whether the gas is monatomic or polyatomic, which is the same as saying it depends on the molar specific heat at constant volume of the particular gas.  You can't tell that from the $pV$ graph alone.
For example, the molar specific heat at constant volume at 15 $^0$ C and 1 atm for Helium (monatomic gas) is 12.5 J/mol.K whereas for hydrogen (diatomic gas) is 20.4 J/mole.K.. The isothermal $pV$ graph for the same number of moles at the same temperature is the same for both gases, but their internal energies are different because their molar specific heats at constant volume are different.
Hope this help.

I did infact mean to say the change in energy in same . I was confused as to how the change in internal energy of 2 "same" ideal gases can be said to equal without knowing the change in temperature . Could you please clear my doubt a bit more with the clarifications I made to the questions via this comment . I think I understood the concept but I'm still a bit puzzled on this topic .

@TEs To be sure I understand you correctly, is your question now "how can we know how the change in internal energy of 2 of the same ideal gases is equal without knowing the change in temperature"?

Yes , that's my question . Sorry for the confusion if any.

@TEs Regarding your question, considering that the internal energy of an ideal gas is considered to be all kinetic, and that therefore internal energy is a function of temperature one, I don't see offhand how we can know that the change in internal energy of 2 of the same gases are equal without knowing the change in temperature.
